# Strong law of large numbers under equivalent measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of square-integrable i.i.d. random variables under the measure $\mathbb{P}$. Under the strong law of large numbers we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nX_j=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[X_1]\right)=1.
\end{align*}
If $\mathbb{Q}$ is an equivalent measure to $\mathbb{P}$ with $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\in L^2(\mathbb{P})$ then each $X_i$ is still integrable under $\mathbb{Q}$ and the strong law of large numbers applied to $\mathbb{Q}$ will give
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Q}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nX_j=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}[X_1]\right)=1.
\end{align*}
As the measures are equivalent, this also means that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nX_j=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}[X_1]\right)=1
\end{align*}
which implies that $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[X_1]=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}[X_1]$. However this is generally not the case.

Can anyone find where the argument above breaks down?

Comment: Is [this the notion of equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(measure_theory)) you are using?

Comment: @angryavian yes that's the one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurred to me that the $\{X_n\}$ may not longer be independent under $\mathbb{Q}$ and so the strong law of large numbers doesn't necessarily hold for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: yes, that is the reason.

Comment: I originally thought this was assumed in your question. So would another way to state the conclusion is "If $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent measures such that the $X_i$ are i.i.d. under both measures, then $E_P[X_1] = E_Q[X_1]$ necessarily."?

Comment: @angryavian Yes, as the strong law can then also be applied to $\mathbb{Q}$.